# How to use vba to position attachment in body of email in outlook?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have my vba code automatically display an e-mail in outlook.  I am having trouble making the attachment appear as an icon in the body of the message (pic 1).  I have no trouble making it show up under the subject line (pic 2).

```
 With OutMail
    .To = MailList
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Teddy Bear Test"
    .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:13'> Hello Team: <br><br> Thank You<br><br>"
    .Attachments.Add teddybear.xlsx, , 999
    .Display
End With
```

What do I need to do to fix my code?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This article might be helpful in using Outlook.

https://support.office.com/en-MY/article/Why-do-some-attachments-appear-in-the-message-body-12829ec7-6cd8-4992-9621-3d1572810335

Answer (score 0):

Change the format like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AttachmentInBody()

Dim OutMail As MailItem

Set OutMail = Application.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail

    .To = "MailList"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Teddy Bear Test"

    .Display

    If .BodyFormat <> olFormatRichText Then .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText

    .body = "Hello Team:" & vbCr & vbCr & "Thank You" & vbCr

    .Attachments.Add teddybear.xlsx, , 999

End With

Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```